# Download card in laravel with qrcode and image use bootstrap

Tags: php, laravel-5, bootstrap-4, qr-code

I have created a card with an image and QR Code. I have tried to downloaded it in PDF form with `dompdf`, also with `snappy`, but my problem is that I use much bootstrap. I've tried to change the time of execution in PHP ini but again the card is downloaded without image. I have tried it with my below code:

My Controller :

```
 public function downloadPDF()
{
    $cards = Card::all(); 

    foreach ($cards as $card) {
        if ($cards->last()== $card) {

            $data = [
                'image'=>'images/patient2.jpg',
                'qrcode'=>'generated_qrcodes/'.$card->cin.'.png',
                'nom'=>$card->nom,
                'cin'=>$card->cin,
                'prenom'=>$card->prenom,
                'dateNaissance'=>$card->dateNaissance,
                'dateAffection'=>$card->dateaffection

            ];
        }
    }
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('cards.cardPdf',$data);
    return $pdf->download('card.pdf');

}
```

My blade :

```
<div class="card w-50 ">        
    <div class="card-body bg-light ">
        <div id="id_div">
            <img class="carte" src="{{ asset($image) }}">                                                                      
        </div>
        <div>            
            <h5 class="card-title text-black"> Nom & Prénom :{{ $nom }} {{ $prenom }} </h5>
            <h5 class="card-title text-black"> Date Naissance : {{ $dateNaissance }}</h5>
            <h5 class="card-title text-black"> CIN : {{ $cin }}</h5>
            <h5 class="card-title text-black"> Date d'affectation : {{ $dateAffectation }}</h5>      
        </div>
        <div class=" text-right">
            <br>                    
            <img src="{{ asset( $qrcode) }}" alt="">                                                                                                          
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? What is going wrong? I dont think this is a lot of bootstrap components. I think something else is going wrong. Checked the logs yet?

Comment: The card is downloaded without image and without QR code this is my problem I've tried to make some change but the same problem  I have tried it with my below code :
        $cards = Card::all();
        foreach ($cards as $card) {
        if ($cards->last()== $card) {
 $data = [
 'image'=>'images/patient2.jpg',
'qrcode'=>'generated_qrcodes/'.$card->cin.'.png'      
'nom'=>$card->nom,
 'cin'=>$card->cin,
 'prenom'=>$card->prenom
 ];
 }
$pdf = PDF::loadView('cards.cardPdf',$data);
return $pdf->download('card.pdf')

Comment: Please paste your code in your question and format it. This is not readable.

Comment: @Fjarlaegur the new code is posted in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if i understand this correctly, you only want the last card to be rendered in the pdf?

The thing is, you are declaring `$data` inside the `if` inside the `for` loop. Thus, the `$data` variable is not accessible outside of it. Also, if it were not for the `if` the `for` loop would reassign the variable each time. I also think you should leverage the Eloquent methods. And why are you selecting all cards when you are only going to use the last one?

Shortest solution if only the last item is needed:

```
$cards = Card::latest()->first(); 

$data = [
    'image'=>'images/patient2.jpg',
    'qrcode'=>"generated_qrcodes/{$card->cin}.png",
    'nom'=>$card->nom,
    'cin'=>$card->cin,
    'prenom'=>$card->prenom,
    'dateNaissance'=>$card->dateNaissance,
    'dateAffection'=>$card->dateaffection
];

$pdf = PDF::loadView('cards.cardPdf', $data);
return $pdf->download('card.pdf');
```

Comment: When i donwloaded the card i got always the same errors image not found or type unknown.

Comment: Ok so the images do not exists? Then OR your code is pointing to the wrong location, OR the images really do not exist.

Comment: But i am sure that i put the image  in public/images/  and the QR Code in public/generated_qrcodes/

Comment: And how do you generate the URL to the images? I mean, i don't think you can just put "images/patient2.jpg" there and expect it to work. That is a relative URL. What happens in your `cards.cardPdf` view? Oh and where do you get the error? In the document after downloading? Because it seems like you CAN download it? So the application throws no error i guess?

Comment: In my blade i just use this : <img class="carte" src="{{ asset($image) }}">

Comment: In the downloaded document,there is the data of the member but there is no picture.I don't understand why the image does not downloaded

Comment: Can you try it using another helper method instead of asset, like `<img src="{{ public_path($image) }}">`?

Comment: The same result.